# Android : Transparent bar under action bar

Tags: android

How can i add transparent bar under action bar like this :
I'm beginner please advice

[image]

**UPDATE**
It's my code, but transparent bar did not appeared on layout, because map fragment is over transparent bar ,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include 
        layout="@layout/notification_bar"
        android:id="@+id/notification_bar"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_menu"
        class="com.android.fragment.MapFragment"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

AND

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/notification_bar" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp" >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is just a layout like any other. Just create a small Relative or Linear Layout with a transparent background.

Comment: Just use a background color that has some alpha...

Comment: Can i use fragment for it?

Comment: I don't know how can i add details like "result" on this background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example:

[image: Screenshot]

Code for activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.testdesignapp.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#000"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Here is some random overlay text example"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.testdesignapp.FooFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have made the fragment overlay by using `android:elevation`, you can also use `android:translationZ`, it is available in API version 21. I un aware of any other methods of achieving this kind of overlay on fragments.

Comment: When i appearing map fragment on this layout ,the transparent bar does not show

Comment: Post the relevant code so we can take a look at what's wrong ;)

Comment: Give `LinearLayout` a shot setting the `android:orientation="vertical"`. If you want to stick to `RelativeLayout` make sure to set the fragment **below** the included bar! **EDIT:** I meant Align Parent Top for the included layout, don't only set it in the 2nd .xml (that could be it)

Comment: Can you please post the answer?

Comment: Answer updated, sorry about the delay - was busy. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Dear Markus, thanks for reply, i found my answer before your reply,but i am tankful from you for your attention,